# "Flashing" issue w/ jQuery .Show()/.Hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a trivia game for my school assignment and I swear I've done literally everything to solve the issue I'm experiencing. Essentially, without wasting too much of your time, I am using the jQuery methods of .show() and .hide() to transition between different phases of my game. However, whenever I prompt my game to start, via button on-click function, the screen will quickly "flash" of the content that's supposed to be showing up, and then reverts back to the "start" screen. I'm at wits end with this, and any help will truly be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    //set up variables for game

    var timer = 45;

    var correctCount = 0;

    var wrongCount = 0;

    var endGame = false;

    //capturing responses from user input

    var question1Capture =  $("input[name='question1']:checked").val();
    var question2Capture =  $("input[name='question2']:checked").val();
    var question3Capture =  $("input[name='question3']:checked").val();
    var question4Capture =  $("input[name='question4']:checked").val();
    var question5Capture =  $("input[name='question5']:checked").val();
    var question6Capture =  $("input[name='question6']:checked").val();
    var question7Capture =  $("input[name='question7']:checked").val();
    var question8Capture =  $("input[name='question8']:checked").val();
    var question9Capture =  $("input[name='question9']:checked").val();
    var question10Capture = $("input[name='question10']:checked").val();


    //!! If extra time, add audio queues here!!
    
    // !!----------------

    // setting timeout

    setTimeout(timerCountDown, 1000 * 45);

    //functions

    function timerCountDown() {

        timer--;

        $("#timeLeft").text("Time Left: " + timer + " seconds");

        if (timer === 0) {

            endGame === true;
        }
        
        console.log(timer);

    }

    //function to start the game

    function gameStart() {

        $(".playScreen").show();

        $(".bannerScreen").show();

        $(".startScreen").hide();

        $(".endScreen").hide();

        timerCountDown();

    }

    //function for when the game ends

    function gameOver() {

        $(".playScreen").hide();

        $(".bannerScreen").hide();

        $(".startScreen").hide();

        $(".endScreen").show();
        
    }

    //function to initialize the screen before the user presses the button

    function initializeScreen () {

        $(".playScreen").hide();

        $(".bannerScreen").hide();

        $(".endScreen").hide();

        $(".startScreen").show();
    }

    //function for going through responses

    function responseCheck() {

        // question 1

        if (question1Capture === 1) {
            

            console.log("correct");
            correctCount++;
            $("#correctCountDiv").text("Correct Answers: " + correctCount);

        }
        else {

            console.log("incorrect");
            wrongCount++;
            $("#wrongCountDiv").text("Wrong Answers: " + wrongCount);
        }

        //question 2

        if (question2Capture === 1) {

            console.log("correct");
            correctCount++;
            $("#correctCountDiv").text("Correct Answers: " + correctCount);

        }
        else {

            console.log("incorrect");
            wrongCount++;
            $("#wrongCountDiv").text("Wrong Answers: " + wrongCount);
        }

        //question 3

        if (question3Capture === 1) {

            console.log("correct");
            correctCount++;
            $("#correctCountDiv").text("Correct Answers: " + correctCount);

        }
        else {

            console.log("incorrect");
            wrongCount++;
            $("#wrongCountDiv").text("Wrong Answers: " + wrongCount);
        }

        //question 4

        if (question4Capture === 1) {

            console.log("correct");
            correctCount++;
            $("#correctCountDiv").text("Correct Answers: " + correctCount);

        }
        else {

            console.log("incorrect");
            wrongCount++;
            $("#wrongCountDiv").text("Wrong Answers: " + wrongCount);
        }

        //question 5

        if (question5Capture === 1) {

            console.log("correct");
            correctCount++;
            $("#correctCountDiv").text("Correct Answers: " + correctCount);

        }
        else {

            console.log("incorrect");
            wrongCount++;
            $("#wrongCountDiv").text("Wrong Answers: " + wrongCount);
        }

        //question 6

        if (question6Capture === 1) {

            console.log("correct");
            correctCount++;
            $("#correctCountDiv").text("Correct Answers: " + correctCount);

        }
        else {

            console.log("incorrect");
            wrongCount++;
            $("#wrongCountDiv").text("Wrong Answers: " + wrongCount);
        }

        //question 7

        if (question7Capture === 1) {

            console.log("correct");
            correctCount++;
            $("#correctCountDiv").text("Correct Answers: " + correctCount);

        }
        else {

            console.log("incorrect");
            wrongCount++;
            $("#wrongCountDiv").text("Wrong Answers: " + wrongCount);
        }

        //question 8

        if (question8Capture === 1) {

            console.log("correct");
            correctCount++;
            $("#correctCountDiv").text("Correct Answers: " + correctCount);

        }
        else {

            console.log("incorrect");
            wrongCount++;
            $("#wrongCountDiv").text("Wrong Answers: " + wrongCount);
        }

        //question 9

        if (question9Capture === 1) {

            console.log("correct");
            correctCount++;
            $("#correctCountDiv").text("Correct Answers: " + correctCount);

        }
        else {

            console.log("incorrect");
            wrongCount++;
            $("#wrongCountDiv").text("Wrong Answers: " + wrongCount);
        }

        //question 10

        if (question10Capture === 1) {

            console.log("correct");
            correctCount++;
            $("#correctCountDiv").text("Correct Answers: " + correctCount);

        }
        else {

            console.log("incorrect");
            wrongCount++;
            $("#wrongCountDiv").text("Wrong Answers: " + wrongCount);
        }
    }

    //calling initializeScreen function

    initializeScreen();

    //start game click event

    $("#startButton").on("click", function() {

        gameStart();

        responseCheck();

        if (endGame) {
            
            console.log("times up!")

            gameOver();
        }

    });

    //if the submit button is pressed before the time runs out

    $("#submitButton").on("click", gameOver);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title> Poke-Trivia </title>

    <!--Meta-Viewport tag-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    

    <!--jQuery Link-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <!--javascript link-->
    <script src="assets/javascript/app.js"></script>

    <!--CSS link-->
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--Google Fonts link-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oregano|Sedgwick+Ave" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

    <h1> Pokemon Trivia </h1>

    <form>

        <!--START SCREEN BEGINS-->
        <div class="startScreen">

            <h2> Press the Pokeball to start! </h2>

            <button id="startButton"></button>

        </div>
        <!--END OF START SCREEN-->
        

        <h2 class="bannerScreen"> Answer 'em All ! </h2>

        <h2 class="bannerScreen" id="timeLeft"> Time Left: 45 seconds </h3>


        <!--START OF QUESTIONS-->

        <div class="playScreen">

            <p> Question 1: What is HM04 in GEN 1 (Red/Blue/Yellow)? </p>
            <hr>

                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="0" id="1A">
                    <label for="1A"> Cut </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="0" id="1B">
                    <label for="1B"> Surf </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1" id="1C">
                    <label for="1C"> Strength </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="0" id="1D">
                    <label for="1D"> Rock Smash </label>
                </div>
            <br>
            
            <p> Question 2: Who is the Gym Leader of Fuschia City in GEN 2/4 (Silver/Gold/Diamond/Pearl/Platinum)?</p>
            <hr>

                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="0" id="2A">
                    <label for="2A"> Chuck </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="0" id="2B">
                    <label for="2B"> Koga </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="0" id="2C">
                    <label for="2C"> Whitney </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="1" id="2D">
                    <label for="2D"> Janine </label>
                </div>
            <br>

            <p> Question 3: Which Water-type Pokemon was a "Starter" for GEN 2/4 (Silver/Gold/Diamond/Pearl/Platinum)?</p>
            <hr>

                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="question3" value="1" id="3A">
                    <label for="3A"> Totodile </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question3" value="0" id="3B">
                    <label for="3B"> Oshawott </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question3" value="0" id="3C">
                    <label for="3C"> Piplup </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question3" value="0" id="3D">
                    <label for="3D"> Mudkip </label>
                </div>
            <br>

            <p> Question 4: How many Legendary Pokemon were introduced in GEN 3 (Ruby/Sapphire/Emerald)?</p>
            <hr>

                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="question4" value="0" id="4A">
                    <label for="4A"> 3 </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question4" value="1" id="4B">
                    <label for="4B"> 8 </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question4" value="0" id="4C">
                    <label for="4C"> 6 </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question4" value="0" id="4D">
                    <label for="4D"> 2 </label>
                </div>
            <br>

            <p> Question 5: In what region did GEN 6 (X/Y) take place?</p>
            <hr>

                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="question5" value="0" id="5A">
                    <label for="5A"> Johto </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question5" value="0" id="5B">
                    <label for="5B"> Unova </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question5" value="1" id="5C">
                    <label for="5C"> Kalos </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question5" value="0" id="5D">
                    <label for="5D"> Sinnoh </label>
                </div>
            <br>

            <p> Question 6: In GEN 7 (Sun/Moon), what "notable" exclusion was present in the game, when compared to its predecessors?</p>
            <hr>

                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="question6" value="1" id="6A">
                    <label for="6A"> Bicycles </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question6" value="0" id="6B">
                    <label for="6B"> Rare Candies </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question6" value="0" id="6C">
                    <label for="6C"> Pokemon Daycare </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question6" value="0" id="6D">
                    <label for="6D"> A Rival </label>
                </div>
            <br>

            <p> Question 7: In which year did the first ever Pokemon movie, featuring Mewtwo and Mew, release? </p>
            <hr>

                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="question7" value="0" id="7A">
                    <label for="7A"> 1998 </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question7" value="1" id="7B">
                    <label for="7B"> 1999 </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question7" value="0" id="7C">
                    <label for="7C"> 2000 </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question7" value="0" id="7D">
                    <label for="7D"> 2001 </label>
                </div>
            <br>

            <p> Question 8: TRUE OR FALSE: Mark Hamill, of Star Wars fame, provided the voice of Entei in Pokemon 3: The Movie? </p>
            <hr>

                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="question8" value="0" id="8A">
                    <label for="8A"> True </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question8" value="1" id="8B">
                    <label for="8B"> False </label>
                </div>
            <br>

            <p> Question 9: Is it possible to teach "Fly" to Scyther (Bug, Flying type)? </p>
            <hr>

                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="question9" value="0" id="9A">
                    <label for="9A"> Yes, he does have wings after all. </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question9" value="1" id="9B">
                    <label for="9B"> No, Game Freak hates him. </label>
                </div>
            <br>

            <p> Question 10: How many current, potential evolutions are there for Evee? </p>
            <hr>

                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="question10" value="0" id="10A">
                    <label for="10A"> 5 </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question10" value="0" id="10B">
                    <label for="10B"> 6 </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question10" value="0" id="10C">
                    <label for="10C"> 7 </label>

                    <input type="radio" name="question10" value="1" id="10D">
                    <label for="10D"> 8 </label>
                </div>
            <br>

            <button id="submitButton" type="submit">Submit Answers</button>
        </div>

        <!-- End of Questions -->

        <!-- Start of End Screen -->

        <div class="endScreen">

            <h2> Here are your results </h2>
            <hr id="endScreenHr">

            <h2 id="correctCountDiv"> Correct Answers: </h2>
            <h2 id="wrongCountDiv"> Wrong Answers: </h2>

        </div>

        <!-- End of End Screen -->

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My resolution for this was to place `event.preventDefault();` after my on click functions to prevent the form from naturally refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

Change `button` `type` from `submit` to `button`

```
<button id="submitButton" type="button">Submit Answers</button>
```

Comment: I went ahead and did this but it didn't necessarily resolve my issue. Thanks though, I should probably do this anyways.